# Can't open Xcode project in Xcode 4.5 after opening it in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode4.5, xcode5

I'm working with another iOS programmer together on a project. Other programmer installed Xcode 5 on his computer and opened the project. After he sent me the project, I can't open it in my older Xcode 4.5. First I got the following error: 
**The document "MainStoryboard.storyboard" could not be opened. Could not read archive.
Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's Development Target to preserve compatibility.**

Then I opened the storyboard in source code and changed the version from 3.0 to 2.0 (and later to 1.0).
After that, I tried to open the storyboard in Interface Builder and got the following error:

**The document "MainStoryboard.storyboard" could not be opened. Failed to unarchive element named "tableViewCellContentView".
Edit this document with a newer version of Xcode.**

Do you have any idea or suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Better if you upgrade the version of XCode to 5. If you have problem downloading the XCode from app store, then you can use the technique mentioned in the following SO thread:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143723/xcode-5-restarts-downloading)

Comment: check my answer below, it might help you.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me with XCode 4.5.1:

Open the storyboard file as source code, change the version from 3.0 to 2.0 and replace all occurrences of 'tableViewCellContentView' with 'view'

Answer (score 3):

You can open the project in newer version of XCode and then downgrade the Storyboard to run in XCode 4.5. I have tried this and it has worked for me. Steps are being outlined here for clarity :

1. Open the storyboard
2. Open Identity and Type tag in your right view of Xcode.
3. Set the value of Development in Document Versioning to "Xcode 4.2" (my default value is "Default Version (Xcode 4.1)".
4. Change the value of Deployment from Project SDK Version (iOS 5.0) to iOS 5.0, then back to Project SDK Version (iOS 5.0)

Comment: Can you add steps to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I resolved this in this way:

- Open your project in xcode 4.5
- Select the xib(FormViewController.xib, in your case).
- Select the File Inspector.
- Under the Interface Builder Document set Deployment to iOS 6.0(This might be set to iOS7+).

Hopes this could resolve your problem. It resolved mine...