# XCode 5 restarts downloading

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Hi I'm trying to download XCode 5 for 7 days. My internet connection is slow. It takes about 15 to 16 hours to download 2 GB. But XCode restarts after downloading 500 mb or 1GB or 1.5 GB (anytime). Is there any solution for it? or Is there any offline installer for this application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try downloading it through a browser instead of the AppStore, you can go to the [Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) to download a DMG with your browser. It's in the Xcode 5 section. When you expand it, there is a link to the DMG:

[image]

You will need to be part of the Member Center to login. You can use the same page to download other things, such as documentation sets and the command line tools.